# python : how to change screen with list data after sign up in kivy

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I am new to python kivy.Can anyone help me that how to change screen with insert data list after registraion.

I am click on submit button then new record insert in database after that i want to new screen with all registration entry but how it is possible.i don't know.
Thnaks in advance

File # main.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.window import Window
import sqlite3 as lite

Window.size = (600,200)

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class LblTxt(BoxLayout):
    from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
    theTxt = ObjectProperty(None)

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('main.kv')
        return self.root

    def do_login(self, *args):

        con = lite.connect('demo.db')

        con.text_factory = str
        cur = con.cursor()

        cur.execute("INSERT INTO user ('first_name','last_name','email','password') VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", (args[0],args[1],args[2],args[3]))
        con.commit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

## main.kv

```
<LblTxt@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    lblTxtIn: 'default'
    theTxt: iAmTxt
    Label:
        text: root.lblTxtIn
    TextInput:
        id: iAmTxt
        text: ''

<MyLayout@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    LblTxt:
        id: lt0
        lblTxtIn: 'First Name'

    LblTxt:
        id: lt1
        lblTxtIn: 'Last Name'

    LblTxt:
        id: lt2
        lblTxtIn: 'Email'

    LblTxt:
        id: lt3
        lblTxtIn: 'Password'


    Button:
        text: 'Submit'
        on_release:
            app.do_login(lt0.theTxt.text, lt1.theTxt.text, lt2.theTxt.text ,lt3.theTxt.text)

MyLayout
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using ScreenManager to go from Login screen to another screen e.g. Settings. Please refer to the example below for details.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
import sqlite3 as lite

Window.size = (600, 200)


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    login = ObjectProperty(None)


class LoginScreen(Screen):
    def do_login(self, *args):

        con = lite.connect('demo.db')

        con.text_factory = str
        cur = con.cursor()

        cur.execute("INSERT INTO user ('first_name','last_name','email','password') VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", (args[0],args[1],args[2],args[3]))
        con.commit()

        if args[3] == "pwd":
            self.manager.current = "settings"


class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<LblTxt@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    lblTxtIn: 'default'
    theTxt: iAmTxt
    Label:
        text: root.lblTxtIn
    TextInput:
        id: iAmTxt
        text: ''

<MyScreenManager>:
    login: login
    LoginScreen:
        id: login
        name: "login"
    SettingsScreen:
        name: "settings"


<LoginScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        LblTxt:
            id: lt0
            lblTxtIn: 'First Name'

        LblTxt:
            id: lt1
            lblTxtIn: 'Last Name'

        LblTxt:
            id: lt2
            lblTxtIn: 'Email'

        LblTxt:
            id: lt3
            lblTxtIn: 'Password'

        Button:
            text: 'Submit'
            on_release:
                app.root.login.do_login(lt0.theTxt.text, lt1.theTxt.text, lt2.theTxt.text ,lt3.theTxt.text)

<SettingsScreen>:
    Label:
        text: "Settings Screen"
```

### Output

[image: App Starup]

[image: Settings Screen]